# query to hierarchical mapper

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models, related with many-to-many, one of them is hierarchical model:

```
#hierarchical model
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


Tag.parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Tag.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
Tag.childs = relationship(Tag, backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[Tag.id]),
     cascade="all, delete")


class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subjects"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, doc="ID")
    name = Column(String)
    tags = relationship(Tag, secondary="tags_subjects", backref="subjects")


#many-to-many relations model
class TagsSubjects(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags_subjects"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tags.id"))
    subject_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("subjects.id"))
```

So, I'll try to explain what I want to do... I want to make one (or several) query, for search all Subject's objects, 
that have 'name' field value like 'foo' OR that has related tags having names with values like 'foo' 
OR that has related tags, that has one or more parents (or above by hierarchy) tag with 'name' value like 'foo'

I've tried to do somethis like this:

```
>>> subjects = session.query(Subject).filter(or_(
                Subject.name.ilike('%{0}%'.format('foo')),
                Subject.tags.any(
                Tag.name.ilike('%{0}%'.format('foo')))
            )).order_by(Subject.name).all()
```

But it isn't correct and "flat" query, without hierarchical feature :(
How to do this by SQLAlchemy's API?
Thanks!

P.S. I'm using SQLite backend

Comment: SQLite doesn't support hierarchical operations directly so the best you could do here is join Tag to itself, as many levels deep as you need to go.  There's some examples of this technique in the SQLAlchemy distribution in examples/elementtree/adjacency_list.py

Comment: It's possible to use "nested set" to slove this problem?

Comment: sure, nested sets is a very hard model to work with in the ORM but there are [libraries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLAlchemy-ORM-tree/0.0.1) to help with it